# The proper use of ご確認ください

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, business-japanese

I often see in Japanese business letters ご確認ください。what and how do I use this phrase?

Comment: Do you know what it means? (That is, have you looked up 確認 in a dictionary?)

Comment: Even basic online dictionaries will tell you what this means... Do you have any of your own working to show?

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to note in real-life usage of this phrase is that sometimes it does not ask for any explicit reaction or response.

Obviously, if the sender is bringing up a problem that needs to be dealt with, or if something is awaiting your explicit approval, ご確認ください will mean *Please look into this and do something about it* or *Please confirm and reply*. Frequently this call to action is written a little more explicitly as ご確認願います / ご確認よろしくお願いします.

In other situations, ご確認ください can simply mean *Please take note that I did something*. For example, the sender may have attached an itinerary that does not call for your input. Or maybe the sender has sent a photo you asked for. In this case, the sender does not expect a response at all.

Some inane emails may even go as far as to use ご確認ください and よろしくお願いします interchangeably. In such extreme cases, this means nothing more than a *Regards* at the end of the letter.

Answer (score 0):

ご確認ください means "please have a careful look at the case, and I am looking forward your response."

ご確認ください is a little respectful than 確認してください and more respectful than 確認してくれる； ご確認いただく is a little respectful than 確認していただくand more respectful than 確認してもらう

subject of 確認してください :You ; subject of確認してもらう:I or we

Comment: Thanks very much ,I am not good at English,so i usually misundertand
Thankyou for you advice

Comment: "ご確認ください is a little respectful than 確認してください and more respectful than 確認してくれる" >> But ご確認ください and 確認してください mean "Please confirm" while 確認してくれる means "to (kindly) confirm (for me)". Did you mean to type 「確認してくれ」?

Answer (score 0):

"Please verify" or "please confirm"

Kakunin = confirmation

go kakunin = your (honored/respected) confirmation

go kakunin kudasai = please deign to give your honored confirmation or "please check this."